# Using BeautifulSoup to Search Through Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to pull information from the 'Key Statistics' page for a ticker in Yahoo (since this isn't supported in the Pandas library).

Example for AAPL:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

enterpriseValue = soup.findAll('$ENTERPRISE_VALUE', attrs={'class': 'yfnc_tablehead1'}) #HTML tag for where enterprise value is located

print(enterpriseValue)
```

Edit: thanks Andy!

Question: This is printing an empty array. How do I change my `findAll` to return `598.56B`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the reason the list that `find_all` returns is empty is because that data is generated with a separate call that isn't completed by just sending a `GET` request to that URL.  If you look through the Network tab on Chrome/Firefox and filter by XHR, by examining the requests and responses of each network action, you can find what you URL you ought to be sending the `GET` request too.

In this case, it's `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com`, as we can see here:
[image]

So, how do we recreate this? Simple! :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com')
data = r.json()
```

This will return the `JSON` response as a `dict`.  From there, navigate through the `dict` until you find the data you're after:

```
financial_data = data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['defaultKeyStatistics']
enterprise_value_dict = financial_data['enterpriseValue']
print(enterprise_value_dict)
>>> {'fmt': '598.56B', 'raw': 598563094528, 'longFmt': '598,563,094,528'}
print(enterprise_value_dict['fmt'])
>>> '598.56B'
```

Comment: This is gold! I'm new to webpage scrapping in general. Are there any resources you could point me towards to avoid similar questions in the near future?

Comment: Check out https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/ and if you really want to do a deep dive, consider http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034391.do .  It's a great skill to have.