# How to get elements of webpage that load after initial webpage?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to download stock option data from Yahoo Finance ([here's Google as an example](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/options?p=GOOG)) with `requests.get`, which doesn't seem to be downloading everything. I'm trying to get the dropdown of dates with an XPath but even `//option` doesn't return anything even though Chrome DevTools says there are 13 instances!

I expect this has something to do with the fact that the parts of the site that actually matter are being loaded *after* all the navigation bars and such, and I don't know how to get all of it. Could you please suggest a method for getting the text of each item in the date dropdown menu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218742/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-through-yahoo-finance

Answer (score 0):

If you open the dev console and refresh the page again (caches might need to be purged), you can see some requests with type `xhr`.

They are usually initiated by JavaScript programs and will load some data besides those provided by HTML body.

That's what you can look into.

Comment: Just to tag onto this answer: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/GOOG?formatted=true&crumb=B2JsfXH.lpf&lang=en-US&region=US&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com see if that link has the information you want.

Comment: In Incognito Mode (which I understand to use a new cache and everything), the console still doesn't give me any `xhr` requests... This is the console that's the second tab in the Chrome devtools, right?

Comment: @RafaelMartins Could you elaborate on how you got that link please?