# Extracting data from yahoo.finance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to extract the current value of the 200-day moving average from Yahoo Finance (so far, I have been parsing finviz.com, Yahoo seems to be faster because of the JSON output).

For example, the 200 day MA can be found at https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL -> Trading information -> Stock price history -> 200-day moving average

This solution is very helpful:
[Using BeautifulSoup to Search Through Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218742/using-beautifulsoup-to-search-through-yahoo-finance)

The request URL looks like this:
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com'

I tried different modules (found a list of the modules here: [Yahoo Finance URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030983/yahoo-finance-url-not-working))

However, I can't find the 200 day MA in any of the modules.

I'd kindly appreciate any hints or suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out!
There's another module on Yahoo finance that returns the information I was looking for: summaryDetail

It's really simple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/GLW?formatted=true&crumb=8ldhetOu7RJ&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=summaryDetail&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com')
data = r.json()
financial_data=data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['summaryDetail']
twoHundredMA_dict = financial_data['twoHundredDayAverage']
print(twoHundredMA_dict['fmt'])
```

In this case, using JSON instead of lxml is way faster!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the 200-day moving average on Yahoo's Key Statistics page is based on 200 calendar days and not the traditional definition of 200 trading days.

Comment: That's a very good point! I wasn't aware of that, but just checked it...